# CONTEXT-Index on Oracle - How does it works?

Tags: oracle

i have a datatbase in Oracle with a table, whichs holds about 700.000 rows.
Now i have set indexes(Context) for columns i want to search for(First,Last and Other_Names).
If i run the Statement below, it takes about 45sec.
But if i change the OR to an AND then it takes just 0.187sec. 
So what is happening here?
And how can i solve it (I need the or Operator)
Thx

```
SELECT score(1),FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,OTHER_NAMES 
FROM VIEW_NAMEN 
WHERE (CONTAINS(LAST_NAME,'Merkel',0) > 0 
  AND CONTAINS(FIRST_NAME,'Angela',1) >0) 
   OR (CONTAINS(OTHER_NAMES,'%Angela% AND %Merkel%',2)>0) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use parentheses when using ANDs and ORs to ensure that they are being performed as you expect.  Your WHERE clause is equivalent to:

```
WHERE ( CONTAINS(LAST_NAME,'Merkel',0) > 0 
       AND CONTAINS(FIRST_NAME,'Angela',1) >0 )
   OR (CONTAINS(OTHER_NAMES,'%Angela% AND %Merkel%',2)>0)
```

Which may or may not be what you want.

My guess is that the final condition `CONTAINS(OTHER_NAMES,'%Angela% AND %Merkel%',2)>0` is much slower to process than the other two (it is more complex).

When you change the OR to AND (and so parentheses are not required) then first the query will look for people whose last name contains 'Merkel'.  Maybe only a few hundred.  Then it filters those 500 (say) for first name contains 'Angela'.  Maybe there are only 10 of these.  Finally it applies the other_names condition, just to those 10 rows.  If that condition takes 0.00006 seconds per row to evaluate, then it will take 0.00006*10 = 0.0006 seconds.

But with the OR, you are now looking for people whose last name is Merkel and first name is Angela OR whose other names contains Angela and Merkel.  So the last condition has to check all the people whose first name and last name **isn't** Angela Merkel, i.e. nearly 700,000.  And this will take about 700,000*0.00006 = 42 seconds.

OK, that's **what** may be happening.  As for **how** to make `CONTAINS(OTHER_NAMES,'%Angela% AND %Merkel%',2)>0` go faster, I'm afraid I don't know!